# C - use printf to show full output

Tags: c, arrays, loops, printf, output

I have a program that is supposed to capture marks for different courses for different students and then display the highest mark obtained.

It displays the highest mark, but I'm trying to get it to output something like this:

"Highest was [student name] in [course] with [mark]"

I was wondering if there is a way to get that type of output

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    const char STUDENTS = 3;
    const char COURSES = 3;
    char students[][15]= { "James", "Keith", "Jonathan" };  
    char courses[][6] = { "C++", "VB", "Java" };
    int marks[STUDENTS][COURSES];
    int i, j;
    int highest;

    for (i = 0; i < STUDENTS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COURSES; j++) {
            printf("Enter marks for %s for %s: ", students[i], courses[j]);
            scanf("%d", &marks[i][j]);  
        }
    }

    printf("\nResults: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < STUDENTS; i++) {
        printf("\n%s: \t\n", students[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < COURSES; j++) {
            printf("%s: ", courses[j]);
            printf("%d\t\t", marks[i][j]);          
        }
        printf("\n");   
    }

    highest = marks[0][0];

    for (i = 0; i < STUDENTS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COURSES; j++) {
            if (marks[i][j] > highest) {
                highest = marks[i][j];
            }
         }
    }
    printf("\nHighest was %s in %s with %d", students[i], courses[j], highest);

    getch(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stephen Docy writes, you must save the indices of the highest mark or alternatively the name and course for the best mark.

As coded, at the end of the third nested loop, `i == STUDENTS` and `j == COURSES`, so `students[i]` and `courses[j]` refer to elements beyond the boundaries of these arrays. Although these addresses would be appropriate for comparing to pointers into the same arrays, passing them to `printf` cause `printf` to have undefined behavior as it will dereference them as pointers to C strings.

Note also that there are other issues in your code:

- you should test the return value of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior on invalid input.
- The return type for `main` is `int`, not `void`.
- type `char` is error prone for the size of the arrays. You could use an `int`, or a `size_t` or a macro for portability to older C standards, or compute these sizes from the arrays themselves.
- Your sizes and the arrays `students` and `courses` have the same size just by coincidence, not by construction. Increasing `STUDENTS` of `COURSES` out of sync with the corresponding arrays would produce undefined behavior.
- instead of non portable function `getch()`, you can use `scanf("%*2[\n]")` which will read the pending newline and wait for the user to hit the enter key again.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char students[][15] = { "James", "Keith", "Jonathan" };  
    char courses[][6] = { "C++", "VB", "Java" };
    const int STUDENTS = sizeof(students) / sizeof(students[0]);
    const int COURSES = sizeof(courses) / sizeof(courses[0]);
    int marks[STUDENTS][COURSES];
    int i, j, highest, best_student, best_course;

    for (i = 0; i < STUDENTS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COURSES; j++) {
            printf("Enter marks for %s for %s: ", students[i], courses[j]);
            if (scanf("%d", &marks[i][j]) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nResults:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < STUDENTS; i++) {
        printf("\n%s:\n", students[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < COURSES; j++) {
            printf("%s: ", courses[j]);
            printf("%d\t\t", marks[i][j]);          
        }
        printf("\n");   
    }

    highest = marks[0][0];
    best_student = best_course = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < STUDENTS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COURSES; j++) {
            if (marks[i][j] > highest) {
                highest = marks[i][j];
                best_student = i;
                best_course = j;
            }
         }
    }
    printf("\nHighest was %s in %s with %d\n",
           students[best_student], courses[best_course], highest);

    scanf("%*2[\n]");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to save the values for `i` and `j` when you find the highest score :

```
highest = marks[0][0];

int highStudent = 0;
int highCourse = 0;

for (i = 0; i < STUDENTS; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < COURSES; j++) {
        if (marks[i][j] > highest) {
            highest = marks[i][j];
            highStudent = i;
            highCourse = j;
        }

    }
}

printf("\nHighest was %s in %s with %d\n", students[highStudent], courses[highCourse], highest);
```